# How can I redirect all hits within a folder, to the root of the folder?

Tags: url-rewriting, redirect

I'm trying the below htaccess 301 redirect, but it's getting stuck in a loop:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /faqs/.* http://www.example.com/faqs
```

Basically, we have lots of sub pages of the faqs folder indexed by google but we have removed that content. We'd simply like any traffic to those pages just to go back to the /faqs page we have setup.

But my rule is running every time the redirect takes place.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with PERL Style Regex but a normal Regex for your problem can be written like

```
RedirectMatch 301 \/faqs\/.*$ http://www.example.com/faqs
```

or

```
RedirectMatch 301 \/faqs\/.* http://www.example.com/faqs
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I couldn't get it to work with the above code, hence no accepted answer this time round. Thanks for trying though.